# Python script (with ctypes) running slow or crashing if a certain modules are imported

Tags: python, memory, crash, ctypes, python-import

**UPDATE 3:** Before you start reading more, please note that I was able to "fix" the problem that I had! It turned out that there was a memory error in the DLL itself. Quite strangely, the memory error (in the c side) showed up only when I was importing certain modules in Python (I still have no clue this). If you are still interested for some reason, please read on ... I have also provided a link to the c program that I used to create the DLL. There is also a comment in the c file identifying the line that (I believe) was causing memory error.

I have the following Python script that calls a DLL for doing ray tracing. The code is functional, and I get the following output when I run the code (with the `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` line commented)

Output (without importing matplotlib):

```
λ python import_problem.py
Time before tracing:  5.92239880841 micro seconds
Ray tracing took 392.607661807  milli seconds
```

I am able to execute the code 100% (in as many runs that I tried) of the time in the above case.

However, if I just uncomment the line `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` then, <s>either the executing time increases by a significant percentage or</s> Python just crashes with the message "python.exe has stopped working...".

(I am aware that I am not using this particular module in the code ... but it is just for demonstrating the problem. I have also tried to import another module that I had written and get the see the same problem).

Also, note that tracing smaller number or larger number of rays doesn't affect this problem.

So far I don't have any clues as to why this problem occurs. Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Thank you very much.

I am using Python 2.7.3 (64 bit) on Windows 7.

**Update 1:**
I have also tested importing few other modules and here are the results -- Importing Numpy, Scipy, Mayavi does not cause any problem at all. However, when I try to import some modules I have created (and used without problems) in the past, the crash reappears.

**Update 2:** 
You can find the c source file that was used to create the DLL [here](https://github.com/indranilsinharoy/zArrayTrace/blob/master/arrayTraceClient.c).

Here is the Python script:

```
# file: import_problem.py
import os as os
import time as time
from ctypes import  WinDLL, c_int, c_double, Structure, POINTER
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class DdeArrayData(Structure):
    _fields_ = [(  'x', c_double), ('y', c_double), ('z', c_double),
                (  'l', c_double), ('m', c_double), ('n', c_double),
                ('opd', c_double), ('intensity', c_double),
                ('Exr', c_double), ('Exi', c_double),
                ('Eyr', c_double), ('Eyi', c_double),
                ('Ezr', c_double), ('Ezi', c_double),
                ('wave', c_int),   ('error', c_int),
                ('vigcode', c_int), ('want_opd', c_int)]

def my_function( ):
    num_rays = 441
    rd = (DdeArrayData * (num_rays + 1))()
    # Setup a basic ray data array for test
    rd[0].opd, rd[0].wave = 0.0, 0
    rd[0].error = c_int(num_rays)
    rd[0].want_opd = -1
    k = 0
    for i in xrange(-10, 11, 1):
        for j in xrange(-10, 11, 1):
            k += 1
            rd[k].z, rd[k].l =i/20.0, j/20.0
            rd[k].intensity, rd[k].wave = 1.0, 1

    start_time = time.clock()
    ret = arrayTrace(rd)    # Call the C function
    end_time = time.clock()
    print "Time before tracing: ", (start_time)*10e6, "micro seconds"
    print "Ray tracing took", (end_time - start_time)*10e3, " milli seconds"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array_trace_lib = WinDLL("C:\\tmp\\ArrayTrace.dll")
    arrayTrace = array_trace_lib.arrayTrace
    arrayTrace.restype = c_int
    arrayTrace.argtypes = [POINTER(DdeArrayData)]
    my_function()
```

Comment: If I must bet, I would say that it is a reference counter problem or memory corruption. Do you think you can get a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The example is quite large and the DLL is a black box :(

Comment: @MariusSiuram Thanks for your reply. "If I must bet, I would say that it is a reference counter problem or memory corruption.". Can you suggest a method to diagnose it?

Comment: @eryksun. Thanks for the reply. My other module does not import Numpy.  In fact after reading your comment, I tried to explicitly import Numpy, Scipy and Mayavi (which I believe are relatively large modules). I could import all of the above and the code executed 100% of the time without crashing (I tried over 25 times).

Comment: @MariusSiuram " Do you think you can get a MCVE? The example is quite large and the DLL is a black box :("    I understand. However, I tried to strip down my code to the minimum so that it can still function with the DLL that I call. I will try to create and post a smaller code (albeit a different example) if I am able to successfully reproduce the problem with it soon. Also, do you think it might be useful if I post a link for downloading the ArrayTrace.DLL file? (I wasn't sure if people would be comfortable downloading and executing a DLL for unverified source). Thanks a lot.